# Configuring VXLAN in OpenDayLight lab

Tags: mininet, sdn, opendaylight

I´m planning to build a SDN lab that consists on two datacenters with four leaf and two spine switches. I want to interconnect them using VXLAN, and use VXLAN too to interconnect datacenters. I am using mininet to build the topology and a VM with OpenDayLight as a controller.
Could you please tell me how to configure VXLAN in OpenDayLight?

Thanks and regards.
Diego

Comment: GENIUS project can be of help ? https://docs.opendaylight.org/en/stable-neon/release-notes/projects/genius.html